# How do I point to a variable name made up of dynamic and constant content?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract specific variables from a dataset, but the variable names consist of dynamic (e.g., `wave1`, `wave2`) and constant text strings (e.g., `var1`, `var2`). The variable names for wave 1 are something like `wave1_var1`, `wave1_var2`, and the variables for wave 2: `wave2_var1`, `wave2_var2`.

So far, I've tried using `paste0` to "join" variable names together, but it throws out an error.

```
clean <- function(wave_var) {
  dat <- select(paste0(wave_var, "var1"), paste0(wave_var, "var2"))
}
```

I'm hoping to write a function that lets me input the wave_var (e.g., `wave1`) so I can extract all the relevant variables in the dataset.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for your error is that you didn't pass a dataframe or tibble as the first argument to your select call. You'd want something like:

```
df %>% select(paste0(wave_var, "var1"), paste0(wave_var, "var2"))
```

It's hard to tell without seeing the error message though.

Also, note that your `clean` function, as defined, doesn't actually return anything.